# Filter JSON data in React.js

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I have this state defined:

```
 constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            open: false,
            customers:[],
            customer:{},
            products:[],
            product:{},
            orders:[],
            order:{},
            newForm:true,
            phoneNumbererror:null,
            shop:this.props.salon,
            value:'a',
            showTab:'none',
            slideIndex: 0,

        };
    }
```

With the following function which contains a fetch, I recieve an array of objects with responseData:

```
getProducts(){
        fetch(
            DOMAIN+'/api/products/', {
                method: 'get',
                dataType: 'json',
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Authorization':'Bearer '+this.props.token
                }
            })
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseData) => {
                this.setState({products:responseData})
                console.log("Console log de products responseData");
                console.log(responseData);
            })
            .catch(function(e) {
                console.log(e);
            });
    }
```

This function is called in `componentDidMount`:

```
componentDidMount(){
        this.getCustomers();
        this.getProducts();
    }
```

The JSON object obtained from the fetch and kept within `this.state.products` looks like this:

```
Array(72)
0:
brand:{_id: "592d3092f42d775da9d38063", name: "Moroccanoil", __v: 0, created: "2017-05-30T08:42:58.242Z", photos: Array(0)}
created:"2017-06-14T18:46:52.508Z"
description:"Aporta una flexibilidad excepcional y proporciona un look hidratado y mate. Aplica una cantidad igual a la punta del dedo de esta arcilla filtrada, emulsiona entre las manos y distribúyela por el cabello. La fórmula de la arcilla purificada aporta al cabello textura y un acabado ligero y mate, y el Mineral Oil Finishing. Complex le proporciona un aspecto sano."
images:["https://storage.googleapis.com/magnifique-dev/olaplex 3.jpg"]
line:"Pruebadelproductolargo"
name:"Nombremuylargoaversicabe"
price:400
profile:"Decoloración"
salePrice:0
sex:["Mujer"]
size:"100 ML"
stock:400
videos:[""]
__v:19
_id:"5941849ce4fa0c7442b0f885"
__proto__:Object
```

As shown previously in the fetch, with this line `this.setState({products:responseData})` I can pass `products` to the table where I want `name` and `price` to be displayed:

```
<DataTables
     height={'auto'}
     selectable={false}
     showRowHover={true}
     columns={FAV_TABLE_COLUMNS}
     data={this.state.products}
     showCheckboxes={false}
     rowSizeLabel="Filas por página"
           />
```

The table called is:

```
const FAV_TABLE_COLUMNS = [
    {
        key: 'name',
        label: 'Producto'
    }, {
        key: 'price',
        label: 'Precio del producto'
    }
];
```

**How can I filter the products to display only the favourite ones of the client?**

All of the favourite products of the client are stored in this other object within the array `favouritesProducts`:

```
Array(22)
12:
app:{created: "2017-07-07T13:34:14.249Z"}
billingAddress:[]
cardLastNumbers:"5262"
cardSaved:"true"
created:"2017-06-30T09:51:59.869Z"
creditCard:
cardNumberSalt: 
expirationSalt:
email:"angel@magnifique.club"
eyebrowType:"Pobladas"
eyelashType:"Rectas"
favouritesProducts:
Array(1)
0:
"594186cee4fa0c7442b0f942"
length:1
__proto__:
Array(0)
favouritesServices:[]
hairColor:"Rubio"
hairState:"Dañado"
hairType:"Medio"
loginType:[]
nailPolish:"Semipermanente"
nailType:"Naturales"
name:"AngelFBMag"
payerSaved:"true"
phoneNumber:
pictures:[]
platform:undefined
salt:
sex:"Mujer"
shippingAddress:[{…}]
shop:{_id: "59108159bc3fc645704ba508", location: {…}, settings: {…}, customers: Array(0), __v: 0, …}
surname:"Marquez"
__v:13
_id:"59561f3f1d178e1966142ad7"
__proto__:Object
```

This object is obtained through this other function:

```
getCustomers(){
        fetch(
            DOMAIN+'/api/customers/shop/'+this.props.salon, {
                method: 'get',
                dataType: 'json',
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Authorization':'Bearer '+this.props.token
                }
            })
            .then((response) =>
            {
                return response.json();
            })
            .then((responseData) => {
                responseData.map(function (v) {
                    v.platform = v.app ? v.app.platform : null  })
                this.setState({customers:responseData})
                console.log(responseData);
            })
            .catch(function() {
                console.log("error");
            });
    }
```

Currently I can print all the products without a filter. The question is how can I filter the products that I obtain, with the favourite products of the client.

[CAPTURE OF THE CURRENT SITUATION: ALL PRODUCTS BEING DISPLAYED](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBFCd.png)

[CAPTURE FOR MELEXANDRE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVoBW.png)

Answer (score 1):

Make a new function `getFavouriteProduct` that would looks something like this

```
getFavouriteProducts() {
    fetch(all products)
    .then((response1) => {
        fetch(fav products)
        .then((resonse2) => {
            // filter response1 on the basis of response2
            this.setState({desiredState: desiredOutput})
        })
    })
}
```

edit:
You can to do this from a single function as well.

```
getEverything() {
    fetch(data_by_get_product)
    .then((response1) => {
        fetch(data_by_get_customer)
        .then((resonse2) => {
            // filter response1 on the basis of response2
            this.setState({states_changed_by_getProduct: response1})
            this.setState({states_changed_by_get_customer: response2})
            this.setState({desiredOutput: filteredOutput}}
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: So getProducts would be redundant with this new function, right?

Comment: Edited the answer accordingly

Comment: When I get the first response should I pass the data into JSON format with `response.json()`?

Comment: Everything you have written remains, just use nested `fetch` statements to acheive your goal

Answer (score 0):

You should use filter & map:

```
isProductInFavorites(product) {
    // TODO: Return true if the current product is in the Customer's favorites
}

render() {
    const products = this.state.products
        .filter((product) => this.isProductInFavorites(product))
        .map((product) => [product.name, product.price])
    return (
        <DataTables
         height={'auto'}
         selectable={false}
         showRowHover={true}
         columns={FAV_TABLE_COLUMNS}
         data={products}
         showCheckboxes={false}
         rowSizeLabel="Filas por página" />
    )
}
```

I'm not sure if you need an array of data or an object, but if you need an object, the function should be `(product) => {name: product.name, price: product.price}`.

Also, I'd like to make sure you know that fetch need you to check the status of the response, like described in the [Github Polyfill](https://github.com/github/fetch#handling-http-error-statuses). And it might be better if the server managed a "favorite" status on each product before returning the list for `getProducts`.

Comment: So, should I avoid using a fetch function and use `const products = this.state.products.map((product) => [product.name, product.price])` above my `DataTable` or am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding. Your `getProducts` looks fine, and it seems it's working. I would just check the status as shown on my link to be sure the server has not returned an error.


Your problem was that you wanted to only display the name & price in your products list. Using a map is the perfect case for this, without changing your fetching method.

Comment: But the point is not to get all my products but only the favourites of the client.

Comment: I might have misunderstood the question. Sorry. I think the best way is to make only one fetch, your server should manage the favorite status of each product before sending the response. If you can't, by the same way I used `.map`, you could use `.filter` on the products list and return true only if the product is in the favoriteProducts array.

Comment: I edited my answer with an example of the filter. I'm not sure where your `getCustomers` is called, but the function to know if a product is in the product favorites should not be too complicated once you already have the two lists.

Comment: Don't worry. `getCustomers` is called in `componentDidMount`, as shown in the question. Adding your code above my table will filter my products or should I filter them in the fetch? Now when I add your code says that `products` is an unused constant.

Comment: I think it's best to filter them in the rendering instead of the state, so right where I did it. If you filter it directly in the fetch, if another data is changed (like the customer selected), you won't have the data to filter anymore. It's more powerful to do it in the render.


In my code, I changed this in the DataTables : `data={products}`. Did you do it too?

Comment: No, I didn't. Now I've done the changes and it says that `products` is undefined. I'll add a capture of my code to show how it looks, because it seems to be not recognised. EDIT: I think that it's because the code is within the return.

Comment: Exactly, the code must be right before the return. I'll edit my answer to show this.

Comment: When I add the code before the return it occurs an error, saying that `isProductInFavorites` is undefined.

Comment: That's what I said earlier. I didn't write this method, you know your data, you're in a better position to write isProductInFavorites. My answer was just regarding the code organization, because it was the question. The data you pasted are not really json, it's hard to read it. But again, it should be as simple as checking if the current product key is in the customer's favorite, nothing hard I should think.

Comment: I tried to complete the function that you suggested yesterday: `isProductInFavorites(product) {
        const customer = this.state.customer;
        if (product._id === customer.favouritesProducts[0]._id){
            return true;
        }
    }` But it says that `favouritesProducts` is undefined

Comment: I can't help without seeing the JSON data, and in real json format (you can do a console.log of customer & product for example).