# React Native filter json object by more arguments

Tags: android, json, reactjs

I have search bar in react native to filter json object.
This is my code:

```
SearchFilterFunction(text){

newData = this.arrayholder.filter(function(item){


   itemdata= item.Nome.toUpperCase(), //How itemdata have item.nome and item.citta?

   textData = text.toUpperCase() 
    return itemdata.indexOf(textData) > -1
  })
 this.setState({

  dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(newData),
  text: text

})
```

And this is my json:

```
15:11:29: Array [
15:11:29:   Object {
15:11:29:     "Citta": "Milano",
 15:11:29:     "Data": "9/08/2018 ",
15:11:29:     "Foto": "x",
15:11:29:     "Nome": "Musica pop",
15:11:29:     "Ora": "18:30:00",
15:11:29:   },
15:11:29:   Object {
15:11:29:     "Citta": "Ancona",
15:11:29:     "Data": "9/05/2018",
15:11:29:     "Foto": "x",
15:11:29:     "Nome": "Food porn",
15:11:29:     "Ora": "21:30:00",
15:11:29:   },
15:11:29:   Object {
15:11:29:     "Citta": "miami",
15:11:29:     "Data": "12/12/2018",
15:11:29:     "Foto": "x",
 15:11:29:     "Nome": "musica jazz",
 15:11:29:     "Ora": "21:30:00",
 15:11:29:   },
 15:11:29: ]
```

How can I filter this object by Nome and Citta? I dont need only item.Nome

Comment: You need to iterate each Object and search for index _Nome_ or _Citta_

Comment: I know but How? can u show me a code

Comment: Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45710032/filter-json-data-in-react-js?rq=1&utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: This is not what I want, I use Search Box that filters item.. in this case only by Nome.. I need to filter by Nome AND Citta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your filter code to below code to search text in both `Nome` and `Citta`

```
itemdata= item.Nome.toUpperCase();
itemCitta = item.Citta.toUpperCase();
textData = text.toUpperCase() 
return itemdata.indexOf(textData) > -1 || itemCitta.indexOf(textData) > -1
```